# how can i fix the wifi connection for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: wireless

My wifi connection is gone, but I got ethernet. Could it be the wireless adapter, I had the similar problem with the erased windows 7, but the wireless usb adapter what I used
doesn't work for Ubuntu. I got Acer Extensa 4420... Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of the wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: lsusb

Comment: What is the ninth character of the command? I couldn't figure out... I'm really a beginner using terminal window programs...

Comment: I assume you mean the pipe symbol | ; it is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \.

Comment: OK, I found it. Appears to be separated at the middle...

Comment: Excellent! So what does it report?

Comment: I typed in "Ispci-nn|grep 0280", but command not find... Should I type the "Isusb" too in this command line?

Comment: Please use the correct spacing: lspci  -nn  | grep  0280. Then press Enter. Record the result. Then a new command: lsusb. Press Enter and record the result.

Comment: Well, it said "no command 'Ispci' found, did you mean 'Ispci' from package 'pciutils' from (main)"

Comment: What kind of Ubuntu install is this that doesn't include 'lspci?' Can you hook up the ethernet and try to install it? sudo apt-get install pciutils

Comment: Downloaded the 'pciutils', and it said it is already the newest version. I installed the Ubuntu 12.04 five days ago from CD, which I created 6 months ago. I even tried to re-install the OS again, but the boot from CD-ROM doesn't work anymore...

Comment: With the ethernet hooked up, please do each command one at a time: sudo apt-get update and then: sudo apt-get install --reinstall pciutils and then lspci -nn | grep 0280. Is your BIOS set to boot from the CD first?

Comment: I did the reinstallment, but still can't find the command 'Ispci'... Crazy...

Comment: Is this the normal desktop version .iso or the minimal version that, as its name suggests, doesn't include many features unless you install them later?

Comment: I don't know that, downloaded the 12.04 LTS version from the Ubuntu site last summer...

Comment: I suggest you try again: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop Obviously, if you can't download things, install things, identify your hardware, etc., there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: Buying a new laptop, most likely an IBM should be the best solution...:) Anyways, thank you for your time and help...

Answer (score 0):

simply taking their solution 2 and tweaking it to look like :

> sudo rmmod -f iwlwifi
>
> sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

If you notice that the wifi speed improved, then make the change permanent :

> gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-disable11n.conf

and add this line to the file:

> options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

save and quit.

If you're on battery, turning off power management could help as well

> sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off

Comment: Thank you, I will try it right now... What is solution 2?

Comment: I typed in "sudo rmmod-f iwlwifi", asked the password, but command not find. I tried 3 more times, but got the same answer...

Comment: @user229479--Why do you believe he has an Intel wireless device?

Comment: That's work with me